# How can I ignore a bunch of words that might have in a text or not, with regex

Tags: regex

I have the following possible texts:

```
Any text here!
Any foo text here!
Any text foo here!
Any text here foo!
```

And want my match to be always:

```
Any text here!
```

I've already tried the pattern `/(.+)(?!foo\s)?(.+)/g` printing the two capturing groups (`$1$2`) but didn't succeed as the `.*` takes the `foo` part.
First question is if is it possible and seccond would be how?

Comment: What language/tool/library are you using?

Comment: It looks like you do not want to exclude lines that contain `foo` but to skip that word. Why not simply remove it first with a `replace()` from the sentences?

Comment: if the match is always going to be "Any text here" what's the point of matching? Can't you just use "Any text here" right away?

Comment: What should happen with `afoobfooc`?

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, I'm using this to add a new "foo" statement on a SVG file with NotePad++ but I don't want to overwrite the ones that already have but I want to rewrite it in the end. Anyway, I did this in 2 parts, first I got the existing ones and put them at the end and afterwards added it to the ones that didn't have it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
(?(?=.*foo)(.+)(?:\sfoo)(.+)|(.+))
```

group1 and group2 ( `($1$2)` ) gives `Any text here!` from line 2 - line 4

group3 gives `Any text here!` from line 1

```
1 Any text here!
2 Any foo text here!
3 Any text foo here!
4 Any text here foo!
```

[demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fdmrvN/1)